# Экранирование кавычек (htmlspecialchars)

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

Здравствуйте!

Хочу задать заезженный вопрос касаемый экранирования спецсимволов. При добавлении в базу применяю функцию htmlspecialchars(). При выводе в `<body>Текст текст "текст"</body>`, кавычки отображаются нормально, а вот в meta title Текст текст `&quot;текст&quot;`.

Как сделать чтобы кавычки в TITLE отображались нормально и как грамотно реализовать данную задачу?

Answer (score 1):

`htmlspecialchars()` нужно выполнять не при добавлении в базу, а непосредственно при выводе  на страницу (при подстановке в HTML-шаблон). При добавлении в базу данных нужно использовать функцию экранирования кавычек, которая перед кавычками добавляет обратный слэш ("\"). Это может делать, например, `mysqli_escape_string()`. Экранирование кавычек при добавлении в БД нужно только для корректного сохранения, при сохранении бэкслэши уберутся и в базе будет храниться исходный вариант (без бэкслэшей). В базе данных желательно хранить текстовые значения в оригинальном виде. Если хранить их заранее обработанные `htmlspecialchars()`, то могут возникнуть трудности с поиском и выводом этих записей не в HTML (например, в JSON или в консоль). Поэтому при сохранении в базу текстовой строки (при подстановке её в SQL-запрос) используешь `mysqli_escape_string()` (на крайняк `addslashes()`). При выводе в HTML оборачиваешь переменную с текстовым значением в `htmlspecialchars()`. Причём, в `htmlspecialchars()` надо оборачивать любые текстовые строки, которые не являются HTML-форматированными, вне зависимости берутся они из базы или нет.